# Which One Is Better For Managing Add Ons For Extensible Plugin?

Tags: plugins, customization, management

How do you manage addons for extensible plugin?

I am writing an extensible plugin, but I feel confused whether to create a custom manager for the add ons install/ uninstall and list them or just using wordpress plugins manager.

Which one will be better and time saver to manage plugin's addon?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shall take a look at [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/) PHP Library. TGM Plugin Activation is a PHP library that allows you to easily require or recommend plugins for your WordPress themes (and plugins). I have seen it being used in many themes in my 5 years of experience with WordPress. I hope this provides you some direction.

Comment: thank you, it is useful information, but is not relevant to my question...

Comment: Sorry if I was irrelevant. Can you please edit the question to have more details and clarity?